# background-image: url() don't work with localhost

Tags: css, spring, html

I tried to put a background image on my login page from a client-server project.
The client part is made using Spring.
To put that background i did:
 `<body style="background-image: url(login_background.jpg)">`

I start the client application and access login page but there's no background image.
When i open the login.html page with my browser there's my background image.

EDIT: Resolved: seems like Spring look for html resources in "static" directory. I moved image there and change url to /login_background.jpg.

Comment: I know it does not make much sense, but can you please try
<body style="background-image: url('login_background.jpg')">

Comment: Same result. What I'm trying to say is that the code works fine if i open login.html page with my browser(right click->open with->chrome) but if i run the application and try to access localhost:port/login there's no background image

Comment: Please check if you are using the correct image-path.

Comment: The code works fine when I open login.html with my browser. So image path is good